# How to get Minimum,Average, Maximum. Std. Deviation for each Test Script run in an ALM Test Case?

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner, alm

I am running 3 test scripts within a test case with 20 vusers each. All the test scripts were successful. I am trying to get Minimum,Average, Maximum. Std. Deviation for each test script that ran but I have not been able to identify how to do that in ALM or through the Analysis tool. I have just started using load runner and do not have much experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default response time report in analysis that comes up when you start analysis.

As you have just started using LoadRunner, you need both training and a mentor.  If your employer has not provided an opportunity for either or both, then you may well consider a more respectful employer who is interested in your success.